# MVC5 Custom View Model, Get Changes, Update Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a complex object that I've broken down to a ViewModel for form. I'll illustrate a sample of the structure but the number of fields are around 60 total from about 6 different entities intermingled.

//**ViewModel**

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   public TabOne TabOne {get;set;}
   public TabTwo TabTwo {get;set;}

   public SomeViewModel(ComplexObject co)
   {
      this.TabOne = new TabOne { Name = co.Name, Value = co.Value};
      this.TabTwo = new TabTwo { Name = co.Name, Another = co.Another };
   }
}
```

All this works fine and I get to the Controller from the View

//**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(SomeViewModel vm)
{
     //TODO: 1. Know which properties in the ViewModel changed for auditing

     //TODO: 2. Update all changed EF entities in the database. 

}
```

1. Before sending the ViewModel to the View I cache the original Value in a Session object and use reflection to compare the two. It's drawn out and I'll have to do a ton of work for any changes. Is there a better way??
2. The ViewModel is different structure from the EF Models, so it's a bunch of custom mapping that will need to be done to Update the correct entities. I'd like to avoid that because of the number of fields. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there any user willing to fill in a form with 60+ fields? My guess is that you can simplify things by further splitting it out in smaller units

Comment: It's for editing information..... Not filling in new information

Comment: Still the same. Does changing the name of his/her pet has any effect on the surname of the owner? Separate concerns.

Comment: You're not offering any suggestions. Why comment at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not sure if this is what you need but for what I understood:

1. You can get the original and current values like this:

   ```
    using (var dbCtx = new YourDBEntities())
    {
       var yourEntity = dbCtx.YourEntity.Find(1);

       var entry = dbCtx.Entry(yourEntity);

       foreach (var propertyName in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames )
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Property Name: {0}", propertyName);

          var originalVal = entry.OriginalValues[propertyName];
          Console.WriteLine("Original Value: {0}", originalVal);

          var currentVal = entry.CurrentValues[propertyName];
          Console.WriteLine("Current Value: {0}", currentVal);
       }
    }
   ```
2. For mapping ViewModels to your EF Models you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/), it can be as easy as:

   ```
   AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookViewModel>();
   var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BookViewModel>(book);
   ```

**Edit:**
Ok, if you need to do it manually, you can use the following method for mapping objects:

```
    public static void MapObjects( object source,  object destiny)
    {
        var modelPropertiesName = new HashSet<string>(source.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name));
        var entityProperties = destiny.GetType().GetProperties();

        var propertyList = entityProperties.Where(p => modelPropertiesName.Contains(p.Name))
                       .ToList();

        foreach (var prop in propertyList)
        {
            var modelProperty = source.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            var value = modelProperty.GetValue(source);

            prop.SetValue(destiny, value, null);
        }
    }
```

You just need to pass a destiny object and a source from where to map the properties.

Comment: +1 for the Entry suggestion. I never knew about that. Unfortunately I can't use automapper. I guess I'm better off just manually doing everything, or ditching ViewModels all together.

Comment: +++ MapObjects.. Thanks for that!